# Group messages from json file by user id

Tags: java, json

I'm able to read a JSON file containing a list of messages and their corresponding authors. The structure of a single message is the following:

**JSON**

```
{
"created_at": "Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015",
"id": 593728455901990900,
"user": {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "GiGi",
    "user_date": "Thu May 17 10:47:49 +0000 2010"
}
```

}

The Author and Message classes (POJOs) contain the fields that we want to parse and a function *toString()* that display the fields in a string.

**Author**

```
public class Author {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private static long id;

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private static String user_date;

    private static String name;

    public  String toString() {
        return name + "\n" + id + "\n" + user_date;         
    }
    ....Getters & Setters....
}
```

**Message**

```
public class Message {

    @SerializedName("user")
    Author author;   

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    String date;

    long id;

    public String toString() {
        return id + "\n" + date;        
    }

}
```

Author is a member class of the Message class and i need to **display the messages grouped by user** but i don't seem to find an elegant way of doing it.

**UPDATE**

A solution would be to create a Map which has one of the Author's properties as KEY (in this sample of code its the author's id), and the corresponding list of messages as VALUE.

```
Map<Long, List<Message>> map = new HashMap<Long, List<Message>>();
for (Message msg : listOfMessages) {      
    long key = msg.getAuthor().getId();

    if (map.get(key) == null) {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<Message>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(msg);
}
```

QUESTIONS that can rise from this solution:

- How would it be possible to display the author *id **AND** name* and their corresponding list of messages ?
- I am not really sure about the elegance of this solution, since the Message class contains the Author class and a lot of unnecessary information are "carried" inside the MAP values.

**SOLUTION**

After adding the *equals* and *hashCode* methods in Author class we are able to map the Author instances as Keys.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 23 * hash + (int) (this.id ^ (this.id >>> 32));
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Author author = (Author) obj;
    if (this.id != author.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And in the main class we can iterate through the list of messages and populate the map correctly:

```
Map<Author, List<Message>> map = new HashMap<Author, List<Message>>();
for (Message message : listOfMessages) {
    List<Message> userMessages = map.get(message.getAuthor());
    if (userMessages == null) {
        userMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        map.put(message.getAuthor(), userMessages);
    }
    userMessages.add(message);
}
for (Entry<Author, List<Message>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey().getId());
    for (Message message : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + message.getDate());
    }
}
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
3037057186
    Thu Apr 30 10:47:52 +0000 2015
1598532858
    Thu Apr 30 10:47:51 +0000 2015
67267979
    Thu Apr 30 11:47:49 +0000 2015
    Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015
    Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015
    Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015
```

Comment: `display the messages grouped by user`? user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the JSON posted is invalid. You need to add enclosing braces and remove the last comma in the user section. So change

```
   "created_at":"Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015",
   "id":593728455901990912,
   "user":{  
      "id":12,
      "name":"GiGi",
      "user_date":"Thu May 17 10:47:49 +0000 2010",
   }
```

to

```
{
    "created_at": "Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015",
    "id": 593728455901990900,
    "user": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "GiGi",
        "user_date": "Thu May 17 10:47:49 +0000 2010"
    }
}
```

You also need to add getters and setters to the `Author` class and make the properties non-static in order for the properties to be set by the parser, in this case GSON.

Then it's just a matter of grouping the messages by user:

```
        Map<Long, List<Message>> userGroup = new HashMap<>();
        for (Message message : messages) {
            List<Message> userMessages = userGroup.get(message.author.getId());
            if (userMessages == null) {
                userMessages = new ArrayList<>();
                userGroup.put(message.author.getId(), userMessages);
            }
            userMessages.add(message);
        }
        for (Entry<Long, List<Message>> entry : userGroup.entrySet()) {
            for (Message message : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + message.date);
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

You can key by `Author` by adding the `equals` and `hashCode` methods to the `Author` class. Something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 23 * hash + (int) (this.id ^ (this.id >>> 32));
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Author other = (Author) obj;
    if (this.id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This way you can group by `Author` instead of `Long`

```
Map<Author, List<Message>> userGroup = new HashMap<>();
for (Message message : messages) {
    List<Message> userMessages = userGroup.get(message.author);
    if (userMessages == null) {
        userMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        userGroup.put(message.author, userMessages);
    }
    userMessages.add(message);
}
for (Entry<Author, List<Message>> entry : userGroup.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey().getId());
    for (Message message : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + message.date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's almost correct. This way i have a Map with the authors id as Key and the  list of Messages as Value, but what if i want to display the Author's name and id along with the list of corresponding messages?

Comment: Just use the author from the first message in the list or depending on what you want to do just get it from each message as you loop over them. Another way is to put in an equals and hash method in the Author class and use that as the key in the map.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this json file `example.json`

```
 [
    { 
     "date":"Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015",
     "id":593728455901990912,
     "author":{  
           "id":12,
            "name":"GiGi",
            "user_date":"Thu May 17 10:47:49 +0000 2010"
            } 
    },

    { 
     "date":"Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2013",
     "id":593728455901990977,
     "author":{  
           "id":12,
            "name":"GiGi",
            "user_date":"Thu May 17 10:47:49 +0000 2010"
            } 
    },

    {
      "date":"Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015",
      "id":593728422901330999,
      "author":{  
            "id":13,
             "name":"HiHi",
             "user_date":"Thu May 17 10:47:49 +0000 2015"
              }
    }
 ]
```

*Author class*

```
class Author {    
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String user_date;
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + id + " " + user_date;
    }    
   //getters, setters,...   
}
```

*Message class*

```
class Message {
    String date;
    long id;
    Author author;
    public String toString() {
        return id + " " + date;
    }
   //getters, setters,...
}
```

*Parse json using Gson API*

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Message> list = gson.fromJson(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "example.json")), new TypeToken<List<Message>>() {
}.getType());
```

*Display the messages grouped by user id*

```
Map<Long, List<Message>> groupedMap = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(m->  m.getAuthor().getId()));

groupedMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " => " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
12 => [593728455901990912 Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015, 593728455901990977 Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2013]
13 => [593728422901330999 Thu Apr 30 10:47:49 +0000 2015]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the format of the json file is  a bit different since i get the json responses from a streaming API. I could overcome this by reformatting the file. The Collectors from Java 8 is a good solution but it gives me a NPE exception and also i would prefer if tthe solution is based on Java 7

Answer (score 0):

use Jackson it give you the ability to match you json with POJO object by using annotation.

Comment: I am able to parse the json (using the GSON library), but im not able to display the messages grouped by user

Comment: make your Message extends hashmap and override the put method, in this case you can read the user and add it to hashmap

Comment: When Message extends HashMap, it gives an exception at this point     :

Message message = gson.fromJson(jsonmessage, Message.class);
    
>  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT